# Managing Docker images over time

Tags: docker

Folks that are building Docker images on push - how do you manage the different versions over time?

1. Do they all get their own tag? Do you tag based on the git hash?
2. Do you delete old images after some time? Don't they take up a lot of space (1GB+) each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how do you manage the different versions over time?

The first thing to note is tags can't be trusted over time. They are not guaranteed to refer to the same thing or continue to exist so use Dockerfile `LABEL`'s which will remain consistent and always be stored with the image. [label-schema.org](http://label-schema.org/rc1/) is a good starting point.

> Do they all get their own tag? Do you tag based on the git hash?

If you need something unique to refer to every build with, just use the image sha256 sum. If you want to attach extra build metadata to an image, use a `LABEL` as previously mentioned and include the git hash and whatever versioning system you want. If using the sha256 sum sounds hard, tags are still needed to refer to multiple image releases so you will need some system.

Git tags, datetimes, build numbers all work. Each have their pros and cons depending on your environment and what you are trying to tie together as a "release". It's worthwhile to note that a Docker image might come from a Dockerfile with a git hash, but building from that git hash will not produce a consistent image over time, if you source an image `FROM` elsewhere.

> Do you delete old images after some time?

Retention entirely depends on your software/systems/companies requirements or policy. I've seen environments where audit requirements have been high which increases build/release retention time, down to the "I want to re run these tests on this build" level. Other environments have minimal audit which tends to drop retention requirements. Some places don't even try to impose any release management at all (this is bad). This can't really be answered by someone out here for your specific environment, there are minimums though that would be a good idea to stick to.

The base requirement is having an artefact for each production release stored. This is generally "forever" for historical purposes. Actively looking back more than a release or two is pretty rare (again this can depend on your app), so archival is a good idea and easy to do with a second registry on cheap storage/hosting that is pushed a copy of everything (i.e. not on your precious ssd's).

I've never seen a requirement to keep all development builds over time. Retention generally follows your development/release cycle. It's rare you need access to dev builds out of your current release + next release. Just remember to LABEL + tag dev builds appropriately so clean up is simple. `-dev` `-snapshot` `-alpha.0` whatever.

> Don't they take up a lot of space (1GB+) each?

[It's normally less than you think](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38805506/1318694) but yes they can be large as on top of your application you have an OS image. That's why lots of people start with [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) as it's tiny compared to most distros, as long as you don't have anything incompatible with [musl libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/).